# HTML appending Async

Tags: javascript, html, cdn

In my html file I would like to append another html file that I want to get async so that the user does not have to wait.

Structure of html file

line one

line two

call to a function which gets the html file from cdn and appends it to current html for the browser to show.

It will also be helpful if someone showed how to do lock the base html till the cdn file comes.

Comment: You're going to need to provide a proper example of the code you are struggling with (read http://sscce.org/) if you want any hope of an answer. Please also read [_How do I ask a good question?_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @foreyez by your standard, there might be no bad questions but there is a lot of question that are already answered and are very well documented over internet. It takes a few seconds to find something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out jquery's load function (http://api.jquery.com/load/)

basically in your current html you'd have:

```
<div id='container'></div>
```

Then in javascript/jquery:

```
$('#container').load( "anotherfile.html", function() {
 console.log("load was performed"); 
});
```

This will the contents of anotherfile.html inside the container div.

Note that you won't be able to do this if you're not on a web server. So if you do this locally with file:// then it won't work. This will only work under http://

Comment: The OP didn't specify the use of jQuery, but only javascript.